# Why are ASP.NET Requests Current performance counter always higher ASP.NET Applications Requests/sec counter

Tags: asp.net, performance

I’m monitoring a web application and I am confused about a few of the asp.net performance counter.

Can anyone explain the different between the ASP.NET Requests Current counter and the ASP.NET Applications Requests/sec?

Answer (score 9):

The ASP.NET Request Current counter is displaying the current number of request currently being processed or about to be processed by the server.

The ASP.NET Applications Request/Sec measures the throughput of the server by how many requests the server can handle in one second.

The MSDN has some pretty good descriptions on the counters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

Also in PerfMon checking the "Show description" checkbox shows some pretty good information.

[image]